# webasset not showing updated files

Tags: javascript, python, browser-cache, ckan, webassets

I have a question about webasset.

I am using ckan. I updated a library in ckanext_geoview plugin in ckan. But when calling this library with webassets comes the old version. What path can I follow?

**webassets.yml like this**

```
openlayers_js:
  filter: rjsmin
  output: ckanext-geoview/%(version)s_openlayers.js
  extra:
    preload:
      - base/main
  contents:
    - js/vendor/underscore/underscore.js
    - js/vendor/proj4/dist/proj4-src.js
    - js/vendor/openlayers/ol-debug.js
    - js/vendor/ol-helpers/ol-helpers.js
    - js/vendor/ol-helpers/ol-layer-switcher.js
    - js/ol_preview.js
```

updated the underscore library to version 1.13.4
[image]

**but old version is coming**
[image]

**What should I do to make the existing javascript files appear? I would be glad if you could help me.**

Comment: have you tried with `ckan asset build` ?

Comment: Thanks for your return. Yes, I tried. Unfortunately it is showing the old javascript file again.

Comment: not sure what you could do now, maybe is caching issue ?! 
Restarting the server, double check the `asset ` tag if loads correctly

Comment: I did "ckan asset clean" and "ckan asset build" again. I restarted the server as you said. My current js file is coming. But the old one still shows up in "/webassets/ckanext-geoview/"

Comment: least thiing that i could think of is that maybe your template is not loaded or gets overwritten. Try to set your extension before the rest in `ckan.plugins`